# in PHP, is it possible to decrypt a string which is encrypted by mcrypt_encrypt

Tags: php

i've got a string which has been already encrypted by mcrypt_encrypt,
the encrypt code is

```
mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,$key,$strInput,MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,$iv);
```

and my question is, is is possible to decypt it with openssl_decrypt, i've tried it with different args,but still doesn't work

```
openssl_decrypt($strInput,'aes-128-cbc',$key,OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,$iv);
```

any suggestion for me?
thanks a lot!

Comment: Why not use [`mcrypt_decrypt`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-decrypt.php) ? (Beware though, as those functions are deprecated since PHP 7.1)

Comment: because the interface is deprecated,i want to use opensll instead

Comment: and the encrypted string is transferred by the third part, so i can not change the encrypt function

Comment: got it, thank you~